# Google Playstore: replace app when using different certificate?

Tags: android, certificate, signature

Due to a harddisc-damage I lost the certificate I used for all my apps until now. It accidentially has NOT been archived in my revision control system. So it is really lost now.

Followed from that now the Playstore does no accept my Apps since they are signed using a new certificate. So what options do I have to really *replace* these Apps? When I search for this problem the only recommendation I found is to rename the App completely and replace it. But : is there a different solution known meanwhile? Renaming/replacing will result in a huge loss of users since many will not recognise the app has changed this way...

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately if you lost your keystore, Google Play assumes that you are not the owner of the app. So there is only one way: "release a new application with new package name and a signature."

I am sorry but there is no other way. Contact Google for help may be they can help (probably they won't help but give it a try).

Comment: OK, response from Google is only a predefined text-snippet that tells me exactly the same like you did. So it seems they do not have a concept for such cases - and it is a pity but your answer is quite correct.

Answer (score 2):

Google Play now has a mechanism for handling lost and compromised keys. It requires you to create a new keystore and a corresponding pem certificate so that they can register you app against the new keystore.

It is described here [Lost or compromised private keys](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en-GB).

Encase this information moves (and for historical documentation purposes) the steps are

1. Create new keystore.
2. Export your certificate with the command

   keytool -export -rfc -alias  -file  -keystore

3: Contact google play android developer support team using there predefined form [lost key support](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/otherbugs)